# How to end editing in NSTextFieldCell inside NSOutlineView after ESC key is pressed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nstextfieldcell

I'm trying to get a custom `NSTextFieldCell` (inside a `NSOutlineView`) to end editing when the ESC key is pressed but cannot find any way to accomplish this. I tried to add an observer for the `NSControlTextDidChangeNotification`-notification but it is not fired for the ESC-key nor is `keyDown` fired in the `NSOutlineView`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Esc triggers `-cancelOperation` in NSResponder. You can try to handle this somewhere in your responder chain.

Comment: Thanks. I ran with- (void)cancelOperation:(id)sender {
    [self abortEditing];
    [[self window] makeFirstResponder:self];
}

Comment: Thanks for this. I have been wondering how to do this kind of thing for a while.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is right. To elaborate: for catching ESC key events, you can override the cancelOperation method in the NSViewController (or any another derivative of NSResponder you're using). Here's what my code looks like in Swift 4.x.

```
class PopUIcontroller: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {

      override func cancelOperation(_ sender: Any?) {
        print("trying to cancel! Here I will do stuff to handle ESC key press!")

      }

}
```

more reading: [NSWindowController can't capture ESC without WebView is added to the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833669/nswindowcontroller-cant-capture-esc-without-webview-is-added-to-the-window/15855895#15855895)